# How to get root access on Android 2.2 with HTC Magic?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, rooting, htc-magic

I'm using an HTC Magic and upgraded the OS to 2.2. Build number of the phone is FRF91. How can I get root access to the phone?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [SuperOneClick](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=803682) root method?